How to make hyphen not be left aligned in ConTeXt in Vietnamese?
I have a weird issue regarding hyphen. When I write using hyphens in Vietnamese, the hyphen sometimes is left-aligned. Changing fonts replaces the hyphens that are error but not remove them completely. Here is what I mean:
tiếng - anh
tiếng-  anh


I think that this might be a kerning issue, but I don't know how to fix it.
MWP:
\mainlanguage[vi]
\setuppapersize[A4][A4]

\starttext
quốc-hội nhà-nước cộng-hòa xã-hội chủ-nghĩa việt-nam an-nam xã-hội
\stoptext

Edit by mickep
The document
\mainlanguage[vi]
% \setuppapersize[A4][A4] % Not needed

\showglyphs

\starttext
quốc-hội nhà-nước cộng-hòa xã-hội chủ-nghĩa việt-nam an-nam xã-hội
\stoptext

gives the following output

If we zoom in, we see that the hyphen is not centered in its box in the default Latin Modern font.


your image looks OK to me, which hyphens do you want to move, the text you show in the ascii vesrion does not seem to be in the example? tiếng-

All of them. I think. The problem is that the hyphen present in the image is not consistent. Some of them is left aligned, while the other are center aligned. the ascii version is there to show the difference i see.

@DavidCarlisle quốc-hội nhà-nước cộng-hòa xã-hội but can it be somehow be extended to all?

as I say they all look OK to me, you get visual artifacts as there looks to be more space to the left of the hyphen in c- than n- but unless you make all letters rectangular that's just how it is isn't it?  I suspect those spaces would look the same if you used unaccented english, ie it's not related to the vietnamese processing

I'm sure you can fine tune the kerning in context, but I'll let one of the context users answer that, but I don't really see any issue to fix in the image shown.

Can you add the output you get with \showglyphs and then point to what you want to change? (See how the hyphen sits in its box)

@mickep how to get the output, i added the command but it didn't show anything?

I took the liberty to edit the question. You can revert or update if I misunderstood something.

@mickep Yeah, how to make the hyphen align to the right instead of the left.

You can change the hyphen-minus that you get into a hyphen (0x2010) that is centered in Latin Modern:
\startluacode
    fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
        name = "myhyphen",
        type = "substitution",
        data = {
            ["-"] = utf.char(0x2010),
        }
    }
\stopluacode

\definefontfeature
  [default]
  [default]
  [myhyphen=yes]

\mainlanguage[vi]
% \setuppapersize[A4][A4] % Not needed

\showglyphs

\starttext
quốc\char"2010\relax hội nhà-nước cộng-hòa xã-hội chủ-nghĩa việt-nam an-nam xã-hội
\stoptext


